# Projecting required fields from Aggregated data in Spring Boot using Spring Data MongoDB API (MongoTemplate)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation, mongotemplate

Below is the code I've been using to project the data I need.

I'm using Spring Data API 4.2.2.

But I'm stuck in projecting a list of projected data.

I'm unable to project the data in the fromCollection into the data in the Document Object.

```
public List<Document> getOrders(List<String> idList, ZonedDateTime fromDate,ZonedDateTime toDate) {

    List<Criteria> criteria = new ArrayList<>();

    Query query = new Query();

    if (fromDate != null && toDate != null)
        criteria.add(Criteria.where("l_appointments.start_datetime").gte(fromDate).lte(toDate));

    if (idList != null && !idList.isEmpty())
        criteria.add(Criteria.where("account_id").in(idList));

    query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria.toArray(new Criteria[0])));

    MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria.toArray(new Criteria[0])));

    AddFieldsOperation addFieldsOperation = Aggregation.addFields().addFieldWithValue("order_id",
            ConvertOperators.ToString.toString("$_id")).build();

    SortOperation sortOperation = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.valueOf(sortDirection), sortBy);

    LookupOperation lookupOperation = Aggregation.lookup()
            .from("appointments")
            .localField("$order_id")
            .foreignField("customer_order_id")
            .as("appointments");

    ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project().andInclude("ROOT.customer_order_number",
                    "first_name", "last_name", "phone_one", "phone_two",
                    "email", "appointments");
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(matchOperation, addFieldsOperation, sortOperation,
                lookupOperation, projectionOperation);

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "orders",
                Document.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

Below is the sample output I'm getting:

```
[
     {
        "_id": "1",
        "first_name": "AMERICA",
        "last_name": "",
        "phone_one": "5555555555",
        "phone_two": "",
        "order": "D",
        "email": "",
        "appointments": [
            {
                "a": false,
                "b": "MANUAL",
                "c": "abcd",
                "d": "2023-10-19T15:00:00.000+00:00",
                "e": "2023-10-20T03:00:00.000+00:00"
            },
            {
                "a": true,
                "b": "ORDER",
                "c": "abcd",
                "d": "2023-12-11T19:00:00.000+00:00",
                "e": "2023-12-12T03:00:00.000+00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "first_name": "ELECTRIC",
        "phone_one": "+987654323456",
        "order": "D",
        "appointments": [
            {
                "a": true,
                "b": "ORDER",
                "c": "fettty",
                "d": "2023-12-11T15:00:00.000+00:00",
                "e": "2023-12-12T03:00:00.000+00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Below is the sample response I need:

```
[
     {
        "_id": "1",
        "first_name": "AMERICA",
        "phone_one": "5555555555",
        "appointments": [
            {
                "a": false,
                "b": "MANUAL",
                "e": "2023-10-20T03:00:00.000+00:00"
            },
            {
                "a": true,
                "b": "ORDER",
                "e": "2023-12-12T03:00:00.000+00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "first_name": "ELECTRIC",
        "phone_one": "+987654323456",
        "appointments": [
            {
                "a": true,
                "b": "ORDER",
                "e": "2023-12-12T03:00:00.000+00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance!!